# I'd like to use the navigation link.Newbie Wang is in the process of hair loss

Tags: swift, struct, navigation

I want to use Navigationlink. I've been a novice for 2 weeks since I started.I am currently learning SwiftUi.
I created "OnboredView" after watching YouTube, but I don't know how to connect "OnboredView" to "CountentView".
NavigationView(){
NavigationLink(destination: OnboardView())
I learned how to make it like this through YouTube, but I don't know what to do now. I put it here and there, but the red errors bother me.
Tell me how to connect "NavigationLink" by pressing the button on "CountentView".
I'd like to click "Chevron.Light" to move on to "OnboredView."And if possible, please let me know how I can get rid of the "onboard screen" on the second run?
I am not good at English.I'm sorry. I'm experiencing hair loss again.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View { 

@State private var animate: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        ZStack{
            Image("rogo1")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .offset(y: animate ? -100 : 0)
        }
        ZStack{
            Image("rogo2")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .offset(y: animate ? -100 : 0)
        }
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Image("images (1)")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .offset(x: animate ? 300 : 150, y: animate ? -300 : -150)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
               
                Image("images (1)")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                    .offset(x: animate ? -500 : -150, y: animate ? 500 : 150)
                
                Spacer() 
            }
            
    
 }
     
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            GeometryReader { g in
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                Text("안녕하세요!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                //인삿말과 회원가입
                Text("기분 좋은 매일습관을 만들기 위한 앱 (  ) 입니다! 시간표와 더불어 루틴을 함께 할수 
있도록 설계 되었습니다.저희 (  )와 함께 계획해봐요!")
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)//중앙으로 결집
                    .padding(5)
                ZStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {},label: {
                       
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            .font(.system(size:20, weight: .semibold))
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(
                    
                ZStack {
                    
                    
                Circle()
                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.04),lineWidth: 4)
                    Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.03)
                        .stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 4)
                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -40))
                
                })
                })
                  
                .padding(-10)
               
                                
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .background(Color.green)
            .clipShape(CustomShape(leftCorner: .topLeft, rightCorner: .topRight, 
   radii: 20))
            .offset(y: animate ? g.size.height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                
            }
         
        }.frame(height: 275)
         //여기까지 짤라도 됨 온보드
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.45)){
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
    })
}

{
struct CustomShape: Shape {
var leftCorner: UIRectCorner
var rightCorner: UIRectCorner
var radii: CGFloat

 func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: 
[leftCorner,rightCorner], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radii, height: radii))
    
    return Path(path.cgPath)
}

 }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
    Group {
        
    }

}
}
}


import SwiftUI

struct OnboardView: View {

@AppStorage("currentPage") var currentPage = 1

var body: some View {

    if currentPage > totalPages { 
        Home()
    }else{
        WalkthroughScreen()
    }
 }
 }

struct OnboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    OnboardView()
 }
 }

struct Home: View {

var body: some View{
    Text("welcome To Home!!!")
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
 }
 }
 //..Walkthrough Screen..
 struct WalkthroughScreen: View {

  @AppStorage("currentPage") var currentPage = 1
  var body: some View {
    //For Slide Animation
    ZStack{
        //Changing Between Views..
        if currentPage == 1 {
        ScreenView(image: "image1", title: "Step1", detail: "", bgColor: 
   Color(.white))
            //transition(.scale)영상에서는 넣었으나 오류가나서 사용하지 못함
        }
        if currentPage == 2 {
        ScreenView(image: "image2", title: "Step2", detail: "", bgColor: 
   Color(.white))
            
        }
        if currentPage == 3 {
        ScreenView(image: "image3", title: "Step3", detail: "아니 ㅡㅡ 이런 방법이 유레카", 
   bgColor: Color(.white))
            
        }
   }
    .overlay(
        Button(action: {
            //changing views
            withAnimation(.easeInOut){
            
            if currentPage < totalPages {
                
                currentPage += 1
            }else{
                currentPage = 1
                //For app testing ONly
            }
            }
        }, label: {
            
        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            //strclulat Slider
            .overlay(
                ZStack{
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.04),lineWidth: 4
               
                    Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0, to: CGFloat(currentPage) / 
   CGFloat(totalPages))
                        .stroke(Color.green,lineWidth: 4)
                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -99))
                }
                .padding(-15)
            )
                })
        .padding(.bottom,20)
        ,alignment: .bottom
          )
  }
  }


 struct ScreenView: View {

var image: String
var title: String
var detail: String
var bgColor: Color

@AppStorage("currentPage") var currentPage = 1

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing:20){
        HStack {
            //Showing it only for first page..
            if currentPage == 1{
                Text("Hello Members!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                //Letter Spacing
                    .kerning(1.4)
            }else{
                //Back Butten..
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        currentPage -= 1
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.vertical,10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                    currentPage = 4
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Skip")//글자입력
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)//글자 폰트변경
                    .kerning(1.2)//글자간 간격 조정
            })
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)//그라운드 컬러 변경
        .padding()
        
        Spacer(minLength: 0)//수평,수직 줄바꿈
        
        Image(image)//이미지 삽입
            .resizable()//크기 확대
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)//이미지 크기
        Text(title)
            .font(.title)//폰트 크기변경
            .fontWeight(.bold)//폰트 두께 변경
            .foregroundColor(.black)//색깔 변경
            .padding(.top)
        //Change with your Own Thing..
        Text(detail)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .kerning(1.3)//자간조정
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)//텍스트를 중앙으로 결집
        
        Spacer(minLength: 220)//minimun Spacing When phone is reducing수직위치 조정
    }
    .background(bgColor.cornerRadius(10).ignoresSafeArea())
 }
 }
  var totalPages = 3
```

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: Thank you, Lorem. I didn't know. I'll study right away.